# Why is openssl required to run .NET core on OS X / Mac OS?

Tags: macos, openssl, asp.net-core, .net-core

The title is self explanatory.

Comment: that is part of how they support cryptography on those platforms whereas they use windows specific stuff on windows

Comment: great, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decision was made early on not to re-invent crypto in managed classes, it caused lots of problems for [FIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140-2) and frankly why re-invent the wheel?

So we use the OS facilities for crypto - we call into CNG on Windows, and then, because OpenSSL is basically the standard on Linux we use that. It also means when there are crypto bugs you don't have to wait for .NET Core to get updated, you just update the OS.